# iOS 3D mixer rendering flags

Tags: ios5

I'm having trouble manipulating the render flags for the 3D mixer.
Here's the code:

```
UInt32    render_flags_3d = k3DMixerRenderingFlags_DistanceAttenuation;

render_flags_3d += k3DMixerRenderingFlags_DistanceDiffusion;
render_flags_3d += k3DMixerRenderingFlags_InterAuralDelay; 

result = AudioUnitSetProperty( mixerUnit,
                              kAudioUnitProperty_3DMixerRenderingFlags,
                              kAudioUnitScope_Input, 
                              0, 
                              &render_flags_3d, 
                              sizeof(render_flags_3d));
NSAssert1(result == noErr,@"failed to set render flags %d",result);
```

This asserts with a kAudioUnitErr_InvalidProperty. I've got the mixer's "uses internal reverb" flag ON, and the 3D mixer works fine otherwise. Oh, if I remember correctly, I tried  all the different scope possibilities as well.
Clues, anyone?

Comment: I have been having tons of trouble with the 3D mixer also, It appears that lots of the documentation is out of date.